# How do I add an environmental variable, but not remove it if it already existed with WiX?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, uninstallation

Right now, I can add an environmental variable on install with the Environment tag in WiX.  Here's an example:

```
<Environment Id="LibPath" 
             Action="set" 
             Name="PATH" 
             Part="last"
             Separator=";" 
             System="yes" 
             Value="[INSTALLDIR]" />
```

However, sometimes, the environmental variable has already been installed on the client.  In this case, that environmental variable must remain upon uninstall.  However, if they did *not* have it already, we *do* want to remove it.  After looking over the [wix documentation for Environment](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_environment.htm), I'm not sure this is possible.  It looks like I have two options:

1. Leave the environmental variable polluting the name space, every time, on uninstall.
2. Uninstall the variable, no matter what, even if I didn't install it.

Is this the case, or am I missing something?  I've been looking, but it seems you either get the option to pollute, or remove always.  Neither seems like the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this but I think it should work:

1. create a property (ENVEXISTS) and set it to 0
2. detect if the env variable exists and set your propetry to 1
3. do the set env variable twice using as condition the value of your property - once as remove at uninstall if it didn't existed and once as leave at uninstall if it existed

Comment: Sorry, my wix is somewhat hazy; how would I do a conditional?

Comment: Won't that just do the conditional at compile time of the .msi?

Comment: Fantastic, I'll give it a shot!